# Pulling ETH-BTC quotes from coinbase programmatically

Tags: ether, python, coinbase

I am using the coinbase 2.1.0 python api to pull prices.  I have been able to pull BTC-USD prices but not ETH-BTC.  My code is:

from coinbase.wallet.client import Client

api_key = ""
api_secret = ""
api_version = "2018-07-07"
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
askBTC = client.get_buy_price(currency='USD',  currency_pair = 'BTC-USD')
eth = client.get_sell_price(currency='BTC', currency_pair = 'ETH')

The last line gives the error
coinbase.wallet.error.NotFoundError: APIError(id=not_found): Not found

Thoughts?